# Tmux cannot switch panes wiht Mouse

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

I have these in my `.tmux.conf`

```
#set -g mouse-utf8 on
set -g mouse on

# Allow xterm titles in terminal window, terminal scrolling with scrollbar, and setting overrides of C-Up, C-Down, C-Left,     C-Right
#set -g terminal-overrides "xterm*:XT:smcup@:rmcup@:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC"

# Scroll History
set -g history-limit 30000

set -g set-titles on

set -g focus-events on

# but don't change tmux's own window titles
set -w -g automatic-rename off

set-option -g default-shell /bin/zsh
```

I cannot use my mouse or change focus to different panes without using the shortcuts. I also cannot switch tabs without using the shortcuts. I'm using tmux 2.1 .

Answer (score -1):

For to switch between panes and windows on your session, add the following to your .tmux.conf

`set -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on`

As an additional aid, it can be useful to use the mouse to resize panes too, for this, use the this line: 
`set -g mouse-resize-pane on`

Comment: thanks @liam_g, but those are no longer options in tmux 2.1